# How find the value of the $x+y$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations

**Question:**

> let $x,y\in \Bbb R $, and such
>   $$\begin{cases}
> 3x^3+4y^3=7\\
> 4x^4+3y^4=16
> \end{cases}$$
>
> Find the $x+y$

This problem is from china some BBS

My idea: since
$$(3x^3+4y^3)(4x^4+3y^4)=12(x^7+y^7)+x^3y^3(9y+16x)=112$$
$$(3x^3+4y^3)^2+(4x^4+3y^4)^2=9(x^6+y^8)+16(y^6+x^8)+24x^3y^3(1+xy)=305$$

then I can't  Continue

Comment: By $R$ you mean $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: It appears that there are two real solutions $(x,y)$ which yield two different values of $x+y$. http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=3x%5E3%2B4y%5E3+%3D+7%2C+4x%5E4%2B3y%5E4+%3D+16

Comment: @Squirtle,yes, That's mean

Comment: You are basically asking us for the intersection of two [superellipses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superellipse), of which the latter is similar to a [squircle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squircle).

Comment: Would you double check the source, and if possible, link to it online somewhere? As JimmyK4542 points out, if we cheat and use technology, we can see that $x+y$ can take _two_ different values. So it seems questionable that this problem is worded correctly. Either that, or there just was a mistake by its author in the first place.

Comment: When complaining about the _two_ solutions $x+y$ , suppose instead $3x^3+4y^3=7$ and $4x^4+3y^4=7$ . Then trivially $x=y=1$ . But I don't think the OP wants to ask such a simple question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the question is typed correctly as shown, there are two unique real solutions.  Let $$\begin{align*} u(z) &= -983749-111132z^3+786432z^4+71442z^6-196608z^8-20412z^9+18571z^{12}, \\ v(z) &= -178112-351232z^3+186624z^4+301056z^6-34992z^8-114688z^9+18571z^{12}. \end{align*}$$ These polynomials have exactly two distinct real roots; let $r(u,+)$, $r(u,-)$ be the positive and negative real roots of $u$, and $r(v,+)$, $r(v,-)$ be the positive and negative real roots of $v$, respectively.  Then $$(x,y) \in \{(r(u,-),r(v,+)), (r(u,+),r(v,-))\}$$ are the desired solutions.  The sum $x+y$ can then be expressed by the solution to a third polynomial  $$f(z) = 819447-537600z-8998752z^3+3291428z^3+22132992z^4-17875200z^5+3163146z^6+1042512z^8-437500z^9+18571z^{12},$$ for which there are again two real roots, both positive.  All of these polynomials are irreducible.  So I **highly doubt** that this is a problem that can be reasonably solved by hand.

Comment: What's the big deal if you can't solve by hand, indeed, but there exist things in the world, called computers, for quite some time? And it seems that you have made the problem far more complicated than the original.

Comment: Maybe an interesting adaptation of this question: what conditions must the integer coefficients of the system satisfy in order to have rational solutions?

Comment: @HandeBruijn: Given that the bounty asks if this can be solved by hand, it seems to me that this answer is entirely reasonable in proceeding analytically.

Comment: @HandeBruijn You seem to be implying that I have unnecessarily complicated the answer, when I have done nothing of the sort.  The fact is that the solution of a polynomial system in general involves polynomials of higher degree than the original system; e.g., just try solving $$\begin{align*} x^2 + 2xy + 3y^2 &= 5, \\ x^2 - 3xy + 2y^2 - 4x &= 1. \end{align*}$$  Two simple conic sections.  My point is that there is no "simple" way to get at the answer.  What I have written above is about as simple as it gets.

Comment: @Semiclassical +1 Indeed.  And instead of rational, I'll even settle for "polynomial of lower degree," or to be completely generous, "solution by radicals."

Comment: I think I may propose this as another question: which superellipses with rational coefficients have rational roots? Reducible roots? Solvable roots? I imagine it's a topic within algebraic geometry.

Comment: @heropup: See the answer by 'mwomath' as an illustration of what happens if someone has no idea what the numbers are like, numerically.

Comment: @Semiclassical: As long as "proceeding" does indeed exist, you'll find nothing but agreement on my side.

Comment: @HandeBruijn: Indeed. Hence why I wonder about the solubility conditions of such systems.

Comment: If either of you are interested, here's the [question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/868635) I made. @HandeBruijn

Comment: Perhaps, that's trivial - but how did you get $u$ and $v$?

Answer (score 3):

Here comes a *drawing* from a credible (Delphi Pascal) source (-:

[image]

Viewport:

```
  xmin := -4; xmax := +4;
  ymin := -4; ymax := +4;
```

Color assignment:
$$
\begin{cases}
\color{red}{3x^3+4y^3=7}\\
\color{green}{4x^4+3y^4=16}
\end{cases}
$$
Hope this helps. (Now thinking about the rest ..)

EDIT. A parameter representation for the curve $\;3x^3+4y^3=7\;$ is:
$$
x(t) = -\sqrt[3]{\frac{t}{3}} \qquad ; \qquad y(t) = \sqrt[3]{\frac{t+7}{4}}
$$
This turns the problem into seeking zeroes of a one-dimensional function:
$$
   f(t) = 4 x^4(t) + 3 y^4(t) - 16
$$
Standard numerical methods can be employed for this purpose.
[Newton-Raphson](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method) and
[Regula Falsi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_position_method)
have been successful here. Our (double precision) results are:
$$
t = 3.56874527617414 \quad \Longrightarrow \quad
(x,y) = ( -1.05957433921527 , +1.38246606572819 ) \\
t = -8.23503156460535 \quad \Longrightarrow \quad
(x,y) = ( +1.40017183631184 , -0.675884813969605 )
$$
Giving, respectively:
$$
x+y = 0.322891726512912 \\
x+y = 0.724287022342236
$$
ALGORITHM (Delphi Pascal) :

```
program RF;

type
  funktie = function(t : double) : double;

function regula_falsi(d1,d0,eps : double; F : funktie) : double;
{
  Regula Falsi
}
var
  OK : boolean;
  d2 : double;
begin
  d2 := d0;
  while abs(F(d2)) > eps do
  begin
    d2 := d1 - F(d1)*(d0 - d1)/(F(d0) - F(d1));
    if F(d2) = 0 then Break;
    OK := (F(d2)F(d1) < 0);
    if not OK then
    begin
      d1 := d2;
    end else begin
      d0 := d1; d1 := d2;
    end;
    Write(d2,' : ',F(d2),' ; Press Enter'); Readln;
  end;
  regula_falsi := d2;
end;

function power(x,r : double) : double;
var
  M : double;
begin
  M := 0;
  if x > 0 then
    M := exp(rln(abs(x)));
  if x < 0 then
    M := -exp(r*ln(abs(x)));
  power := M;
end;

function original(t : double) : double;
{
  Function itself
}
var
  x,y,f : double;
begin
  x := -power(t/3,1/3);
  y :=  power((t+7)/4,1/3);
  f := 4*sqr(sqr(x))+3*sqr(sqr(y))-16;
  original := f
end;

procedure Calculate(x1,x2 : double);
const
  eps : double = 1.E-14;
var
  t,x,y,t1,t2 : double;
begin
  t1 := 3*sqr(x1)*x1;
  t2 := 3*sqr(x2)*x2;
  t := Regula_Falsi(t1,t2,eps,original);
  Writeln(t);
  x := -power(t/3,1/3);
  y :=  power(t/4+7/4,1/3);
  Writeln(x,' +',y,' =',x+y); 
end;

begin
  Calculate( 1.0, 1.5);
  Writeln;
  Calculate(-1.5,-0.5);
end.
```

Note that the *only* place that is truly machine dependent is
the stopping criterion with 'eps'. As for the rest, the algorithm is
quite general. Also take note of the rather crude starting values $(1.0,1.5)$ and $(-1.5,-0.5)$ for $x$ at the end of the code, emphasizing the robustness of this algorithm.

Comment: Your numerical solution fails to establish whether or not the solution set is expressible analytically, and therefore is unsatisfactory from a mathematical viewpoint, much in the same way that someone might ask how to obtain a closed form expression for $$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{(2k+1)(5k+3)}.$$  Anyone can get a numerical approximation to the above by naively adding terms; others can use more sophisticated methods to get faster convergence; but what is *mathematically* interesting is the analytic solution.

Comment: @heropup: That a numerical solution would be inferior to an analytical one _that cannot be found_ (see _all_ of the other answers), that escapes me. Sorry.

Comment: @heropup: About the "Anyone can get", oh well, you're quite right. I could saved myself much effort by simply invoking MAPLE: "fsolve({3*x^3+4*y^3=7,4*x^4+3*y^4=16},{x,y},x=1.0..1.5 or x=-1.5..-0.5);" . How has "by hand" evolved these days ..

Comment: On the other hand, each number of Regula Falsi iterations in the above algorithm is less than $20$ ! So I could have done them with a _hand_ calculator. Shouldn't this count as "by hand" ?

Answer (score 1):

Defining $z:= x+y$, the equations become
$$\begin{cases}
3x^3+4(z-x)^3=\phantom{1}7\\
4x^4+3(z-x)^4=16
\end{cases}$$

Using the method of resultants (which could conceivably be done "by hand", but I used *Mathematica* because life's too short) to eliminate $x$, we confirm @heropup's result:

$$\begin{align}
0 &= 819447 - 537600 z - 8998752 z^2 + 3291428 z^3 + 22132992 z^4 \\ &- 
 17875200 z^5 + 3163146 z^6 + 1042512 z^8 - 437500 z^9 + 18571 z^{12} \quad (\star)
\end{align}$$

Solving an irreducible $12$th-degree polynomial equation is tricky at best. Again using *Mathematica*, the two real roots of $(\star)$ are found to be
$$z=0.322892\dots \quad\text{and}\quad z=0.724287\dots$$

If we abstract the equations like this ...
$$\begin{cases}
a_1 x^3 + b_1 (z-x)^3=c_1\\
a_2 x^4 + b_2 (z-x)^4=c_2
\end{cases}$$
... then the corresponding resultant is ...
$$\begin{align}0 &= c_1^4\;(a_2 + b_2)^3 - c_2^3\;(a_1 - b_1)^4 \\
&- 12 z \; (a_1 - b_1)^2 \; (a_1 b_2 + a_2 b_1)\; c_1 c_2^2 \\
&+ \cdots \\
&- 24 z^5\;(a_1 b_2 + a_2 b_1) \; (a_1 a_2 b_1 + 2 a_2 b_1^2 + 2 a_1^2 b_2 + 
   a_1 b_1 b_2) \; c_1 c_2 \\
&+ \cdots \\
&- 4 z^9 \; ( a_1 b_2 + a_2 b_1)^3 \;c_1 \\
&+ z^{12}\; ( a_1^4 b_2^3 + a_2^3 b_1^4 )
\end{align}$$

Observations:

- A number of coefficients vanish under the assumption $a_1 b_2 + a_2 b_1 = 0$, although this doesn't really help much, because the polynomial remains irreducible still and degree $12$.
- We can reduce the degree to $9$ with the relation $a_1^4 b_2^3 + a_2^3 b_1^4 = 0$, but that's also not particularly helpful.
- We can eliminate the constant term if $c_1 = |a_1 - b_1| c^3$ and $c_2 = (a_2 + b_2) c^4$ for some $c$. In the original problem, with $a_1 = b_2 = 3$ and $b_1 = a_2 = 4$, this gives $c_1 = c^3$ and $c_2 = 7 c^4$. If $b_2$ had a sign-change to $-3$, then $c_1 = c^3$ and $c_2 = c^4$, which for $c=2$, give $8$ and $16$ ... *almost* the $7$ and $16$ of the original problem. Even so, polynomial $(\star)$ only reduces to $11$th degree.

If there's something remarkable about the solutions to this problem, I'm not seeing it.

Comment: As with my comments in @heropup 's answer, I'm [curious](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/874511/) whether there's some criteria for the integers on the RHS's under which that equation becomes reducible...

Comment: @Semiclassical: With $a_1=b_2=3$ and $a_2=b_1=4$, the polynomial $(\star)$ becomes $$\begin{align} 0 &= (343 c_1^4 - c_2^3) - 300 c_1 c_2^2 z - 11478 c_1^2 c_2 z^2 + 9596 c_1^3 z^3 + 86457 c_2^2 z^4 \\ &- 159600 c_1 c_2 z^5 + 64554 c_1^2 z^6 + 65157 c_2 z^8 - 62500 c_1 z^9 + 18571 z^{12}\end{align}$$ Perhaps you can identify a reducibility criterion in there somewhere. :)

Comment: That is the question, isn't it. (Which is why I asked it as a new question, since stuff like reducibility/solvability isn't really in my wheelhouse.)

Comment: Note that the resultant in $x$ in the case $a_1=b_2=3$ and $a_2=b_1=4$ is a bit nicer (only 8 terms). Still pretty terrible, but I'll take what I can get.

Answer (score -1):

Another idea for you to think about. We have:

$$\begin{cases}
3x^3+4y^3=7 \\
4x^4+3y^4=16
\end{cases}$$

Break it as:

$$\begin{cases}
3x^3+3y^3 + y^3=7 \\
x^4 + 3x^4+3y^4=16
\end{cases}$$

and factor:

$$\begin{cases}
3(x+y)(x^2 - xy + y^2)=7 - y^3\\
3(x+y)(x^3 - x^2y + xy^2 - y^3)=16 - x^4
\end{cases}$$

And so: $$x+y = \frac{1}{3}\frac{7 - y^3}{x^2 - xy + y^2} = \frac{1}{3}\frac{(2-x)(8+4x+2x^2+x^3)}{x^3 - x^2y + xy^2 - y^3}$$

Comment: That's fine. But the question is: how to proceed then?

Comment: Interestingly, I did the same thing on scrap paper a few days ago when I first saw this. I was hoping that I could do something with the expression for $x+y$ by using other manipulations of the given equations, but I didn't get anywhere.

Comment: I also couldn't do anything more of the sort. But I posted this answer, anyway, in hopes that OP might have some more ideas bases on this. Maybe he hadn't seen this approach. I understand the downvotes, and in fact, I never expected the answer to get the upvotes it got. I just wanted to add something to the question, since no one had said it yet.